# I want to get and show images with Drag&Drop methods of pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to get and show  images with Drag&Drop methods of pyqt5. For example,like this image,

[image]

I want to make Drag&Drop space and Image-show space.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QPushButton, QWidget,
    QLineEdit, QApplication)
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *



class Button(QPushButton):

    def __init__(self, title, parent):
        super().__init__(title, parent)

        self.setAcceptDrops(True)


    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):

        if e.mimeData().hasFormat('image/*'):
            e.accept()
        else:
            e.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap(event.mimeData().imageData())) 


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        button = Button("",self)
        button.resize(100,100) 
        button.setIcon(QIcon("gazo1.jpg")) 
        button.setIconSize(QSize(100,100))
        button.move(0, 0)

        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap('gazo2.jpg'))
        self.label.move(150,150)

        self.setWindowTitle('Simple drag & drop')
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 300)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()
```

I expect that if I drag&drop jpg-image in upper left space, the image is showed in the middle space.

But when I drag jpg image to the upper left space, "drop enabled mark" isn't displayed. So when I drag&drop a image, there is no reaction.

Comment: From where do you get the image?

Comment: Are you sure that the format is `image/*`?

Comment: Thank you for comments. I get the image from desktop by drag&drop, but it can't be got. I tried to change "image/*" into ".jpg", but there is no reaction. How should I correct?

Comment: Execute with next change: `def dragEnterEvent(self, e): print(e.mimeData().formats())`

Comment: Printed next sentence. Because too long, I devide.

Comment: ['application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="Shell IDList Array"', 'application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="UsingDefaultDragImage"', 'application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="DragImageBits"', 'application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="DragContext"', 'application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="DragSourceHelperFlags"', 'application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="InShellDragLoop"', 'text/uri-list', 'application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="FileName"', 'application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="FileContents"', 'application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="FileNameW"', 'application/x-qt-windows-

Comment: mime;value="FileGroupDescriptorW"', 'application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="IsShowingLayered"', 'application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="DragWindow"', 'application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="IsComputingImage"', 'application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="DropDescription"', 'application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="DisableDragText"', 'application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="IsShowingText"', 'application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="ComputedDragImage"']

Comment: Which is important imformation?

Comment: If you realize none it is equal to `image/*`, so that you understand `hasFormat()` searches within that list the term you pass, and in your case you are passing it `image/*`, so as it is not it will never enter that if . **Is very important**

Comment: Excuse me, what you say is difficult for me to understand. The 20th sentence [ if e.mimeData().hasFormat('image/*'): ] is wrong, because 'image/*' doesn't express right format, isn't it? And in the above list, there is the right format?

Comment: The mimetypes with individuals, that is, it depends on the application who issues it, that is, we can also create our own mimetype. Let me look for the correct one, so I asked you where you get the image from. You could search which is the mimetype that windows provides for the dragged images.

Comment: The image I drag&droped is the one I downloaded from IE. And now it is saved in my desktop. The format of the image is ".jpg". I drag the image from desktop and drop in the window I made with pyqt5. From this information, I can search the mimetype that window provides for the dragged images? I'm poor at English, so if I couldn't have understood what you say, I sorry you.

Comment: Read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type

Comment: If you do not understand English it is advisable that you publish it in a community where you understand the language, in your case I think it is the following: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: In Japanese, "teratail" is more popular, and I asked this question in the site. But there is no answer, so I asked here. You are my last resort.

Comment: Try with `def dragEnterEvent(self, e): e.accept()`

Comment: The window become to be able to get  all format contents. But, the image is not be showed. Is there some mistake in dropEvent(self, e)?

Comment: Try my solution, if it works, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, check the following link: [tour]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want to drag an image from the desktop, the path of this image provides it through a local url, to verify it uses the `mimeData()`. `hasUrls()`, and `urls()` to get the url, then we get the local path with the method `toLocalFile()`, all the above is implemented in the following code:

```
class Button(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, title, parent):
        super().__init__(title, parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        m = e.mimeData()
        if m.hasUrls():
            e.accept()
        else:
            e.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        m = e.mimeData()
        if m.hasUrls():
            self.parent().label.setPixmap(QPixmap(m.urls()[0].toLocalFile())) 


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        button = Button("",self)
        button.resize(100,100) 
        button.setIcon(QIcon("gazo1.jpg")) 
        button.setIconSize(QSize(100,100))
        button.move(0, 0)

        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap('gazo2.png'))
        self.label.move(150,150)

        self.setWindowTitle('Simple drag & drop')
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 300)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thank you! It works as I thought. I am grad, because you have replied my all questions. You are my benefactor.

Comment: @toma Do not forget to mark my answer as correct, if you do not know how to do check the following link: [tour]

Comment: Now, it is marked as correct? If it is not, please comment.

Comment: Yes, that's the way. :P