# Can't drag and drop elements in pyqt5 while in IDE

Tags: python, pycharm, drag-and-drop, pyqt5

I have an issue with PyQt5 on Windows when starting my code from my PyCharm IDE.
I am unable to drag stuff into the running program, detect the drag events, or get the mouse to show something else than the "forbidden" sign.

When the code is packed into an executable with pyinstaller or started from the command line, the drag and drop works as intended.

For testing purposes, I copied the code from this answer: [I want to get and show images with Drag&Drop methods of pyqt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47647857/i-want-to-get-and-show-images-with-dragdrop-methods-of-pyqt5)

I believe that the process within PyCharm gets somehow isolated from the environment, but I am not experienced enough to make assumptions this deep and wouldn't know how to solve such a problem.

This is the example code:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QWidget, QLabel, QApplication


class Button(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, title, parent):
        super().__init__(title, parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        print(e.mimeData(), "Drag Entered")
        m = e.mimeData()
        if m.hasUrls():
            e.accept()
        else:
            e.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        print(e.mimeData(), "Drag dropped")
        m = e.mimeData()
        if m.hasUrls():
            self.parent().label.setPixmap(QPixmap(m.urls()[0].toLocalFile()))
            self.parent().label.setScaledContents(True)

            
class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        button = Button("", self)
        button.resize(100, 100)
        button.setIcon(QIcon("gazo1.jpg"))
        button.setIconSize(QSize(100, 100))
        button.move(0, 0)

        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.move(150, 150)
        self.label.resize(QSize(300, 300))

        self.setWindowTitle('Simple drag & drop')
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 300)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: When you say *from the command prompt* you mean that you just opened the CMD and then you use `python.exe your_script.py`?

Comment: @eyllanesc I copy the script from the IDE to my desktop, call it test.py or whatever and open the command prompt as admin, then type "python test.py" and it runs. PyQt5 is installed on both the Venv and the main python installation.

Comment: When you run `python test.py` and drag some file then nothing is printed on the console?

Comment: @eyllanesc After some more experimenting and reinstalling pyqt5, starting the program from the command prompt worked for me! I'm getting the print output on the console as expected. I don't know what happened, but I'll delete this part from the question. It seems to be a problem with the IDE.